# How to run postgres docker image in Windows using "--mount" syntax?

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, sh, docker-volume

I am trying to make my Ubuntu-based docker container eco setup scripts work in Windows, cuz new colleague is using Windows.

So I have this script, that works like a charm on my Ubuntu dev env:

```
docker stop my-db
docker rm my-db
docker volume rm my-vol
docker volume create my-vol 
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name my-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=SystemAdmin42  --mount type=volume,source=my-vol,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres &&

dotnet ef database update -p src/My.Data/My.Data.csproj -s src/My.WebApi/My.WebApi.csproj
```

It, however, fails in Windows environment with the following message:

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error
>   response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid
>   mount path: 'C:/Program Files/Git/var/lib/postgresql/data' mount path
>   must be absolute. See 'C:\Program
>   Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

I am reluctant to switch to "volume" syntax, cuz I already use "mount" and apparently it is recommended to use "mount": https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: why you are not trying with `docker run --name some-postgres -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres:tag`

Comment: @Adiii because he's trying to mount a volume, not a local directory path? That said, you could see if `-v my-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data` results in the same error.

Comment: @larsks This works... but how do I achieve this with --mount syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure. Your `--mount` syntax seems correct, and the mount path shown in your error message already looks like an absolute path to me, so I'm not sure what the error is trying to tell us.  If using `-v` works, I would just stick with that. It is functionally identical to what you're trying to do with `--mount`.